# Conditional expectation value of battery drawing problem

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, negative-binomial

A box contains $a$ batteries of which $d$ are dead. The batteries are tested randomly, one by one. Every time that a good battery is drawn, it is returned to the box. When a dead battery is drawn, it is replaced by a good one. Let $X_n$ denote the number of good batteries in the box after $n$ of them are checked.

(i) Find an expression for the random variable $E(X_n\mid X_{n-1})$ and show that: 
$E(X_n) = 1 + (1-\frac 1a)E(X_{n-1}), n≥1.$

(ii) Show by induction that:
$E(X_n )=a-d(1-\frac 1a)^n$

Can someone please help me with this? This question (link under) is very similar but I still can't figure it out.
[expected value of battery drawing problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80434/expected-value-of-battery-drawing-problem)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

For (i) note that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Markov chain with state space $S := \{a-d, \ldots , a\}$ and transition probabilities
$$p(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac x a &: x = y \\ \frac {a-x} a &: x = y-1 \\ 0 & : \text{else}. \end{cases}$$
Thus we can write $$\mathbb E [X_n | X_{n-1}] = \sum_{y\in S} p(X_{n-1} , y) \  y = \frac {X_{n-1}^2} a + \frac{(a-X_{n-1})(X_{n-1}+1)}{a} \\ = 1 + \left( 1-\frac 1 a \right) X_{n-1}.$$
In conclusion
$$\mathbb E [X_n] = \mathbb E [\mathbb E[X_n | X_{n-1}]] = \mathbb 1+ \left(1 -\frac 1 a \right) \mathbb E [X_{n-1}].$$
Since $X_0 = a - d$ statement (ii) follows easily by induction by using (i).

Comment: Thanks for the help!